# regex for sequence of characters in a series but not consecutive?

Tags: regex

Right now i'm using `(.*e.*r.*s.*)` to return a word such as 
`ERrandS`, but i need to exclude words where all 3 the characters occur consecutively, such as `runnERS`. any 2 letters of the sequence can occur consecutive. in the case of 2 characters, it should only include when 2 characters are not consecutive.

Test cases for `ers`:

- Include: `ERrandS`, `ERaSe`, `abEttoRS`, `algEbRaS`, 'vERseS'
- Exclude : `runnERS`, `advERSary`

Comment: What about `verses`? Should that match or not? It has `e`, `r` and `s` non-consecutive (with the second `s`) *and* consecutive (with the first `s`), depending on how you look at it.

Comment: verses can be included. didn't think of this possibility, thank u

Comment: @hooray4horus Add this information to your question.

Comment: @paxdiablo's answer works fine with verses https://regex101.com/r/nNEkc8/2

Comment: @Nick That pattern is not complete.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: @Nick Just look at the matches, they are partial substrings

Comment: @UnbearableLightness gotcha. thanks.

Comment: Perhaps @paxdiablo means `(?i).*(?:e.+r.*s|e.*r.+s).*` ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Was just about to make exactly that comment...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is just to realise that there are two possibilities, on with at least character between the `e` and `r`, the other with at least one character between `r` as `s`.

That would mean you need something like:

```
e.+r.*s|e.*r.+s
```

The format of this depends entirely on *which* regex engine you're using (you haven't specified this) but basically, `*` means zero or more of the preceding item, `+` means one or more, and `|` means either pattern (left or right side) is a match. Obviously, you'll need to add case-i sensitivity and possibly put `.*` at start and end if it's a "whole string" match but what I've given shows how you can match the two possibilities.